# Count most recent renewals by memberID

Tags: mysql, count, group-by, duplicates

I have a subscription table that tracks membership renewals by date. Renewals are for calendar year but members are allowed to renew as early as Oct 1, in which case they would be current until Dec. 31 of the following year . Therefore it is possible to renew in January and then renew again in October of the same year. I'm reporting total memberships by month and I want to avoid counting that as 2 memberships.

Each record has a unique `prodID` but can have more than 1 record of a `memberID` due to the renewal option above. `payDate` is the transaction date

My statement is:

```
$sql = "SELECT 
            EXTRACT(MONTH FROM payDate) as month, 
            EXTRACT(YEAR FROM payDate) as year, 
            count(*) 
            FROM 
                memberDues
            WHERE payDate >= $lastYear-10-01
            GROUP BY 
                month, 
                year
            ORDER BY 
                year ASC, 
                month ASC";
```

I get an output like this (not formatted):

```
Member dues paid by month  
October         46  
November        30  
December        99  
January         42  
February         8  
March            9  
April            4  
May              1  
June             3  
Member Total:  242
```

How do I modify the select statement to avoid duplicate renewals in a report period?

Answer (score 0):

you need to group by memberID to get one member renewal not being repeated.

```
  SELECT year, month, count(memberID) FROM (
  SELECT memberID,
  EXTRACT(MONTH FROM payDate) as month, 
    EXTRACT(YEAR FROM payDate) as year, 
    count(*) 
    FROM 
        memberDues
    WHERE payDate >= $lastYear-10-01
    GROUP BY 
        memberID,
        month, 
        year
    ORDER BY 
        year ASC, 
        month ASC";
    )TMP GROUP BY year, month
```

Comment: This approach causes the list to become single renewal events rather than monthly totals. I get the months each listing 1 renewal then looping through the months again and again until it totals 242. Also, as mentioned in above comment, I need to be sure I'm counting the latter renewal (if there are 2) and that it is totaling in the correct month. See image for sample output: <img src="http://inkari.com/asmc/images/looping-output.jpg">

Answer (score 0):

Counting the distinct memberID's for each month should do the job:

```
                SELECT 
                EXTRACT(MONTH FROM payDate) as month, 
                EXTRACT(YEAR FROM payDate) as year, 
                count(DISTINCT memberID) 
                FROM 
                    memberDues
                WHERE payDate >= $lastYear-10-01
                GROUP BY 
                    month, 
                    year
                ORDER BY 
                    year ASC, 
                    month ASC
```

Comment: This approach causes the subtotals to go away. Also, I need to be sure I'm counting the latter renewal (if there are 2) and that it is totaling in the correct month